# Android issue with AChartEngine: set image in margin

Tags: android, achartengine

Is it possible to set an image to background margin ?
I usually use `mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01))`
but i want to set an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set image as background in AChartEngine as it is out of the box. I don't see any value in that.